# Need jQuery Dialog for confirmation and Send Ajax Request to Controller Action

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-dialog

i have simple tr an td's coming from database

```
<tr>
<td >
  <td style=" display:none"> <?php echo $record['id_to_send'];?></td>
 <?php if($record['user_value'] == 1)
 <a href="#"><img src="Green.png" /></a>
 else <a href="#"><img src="Red.png" /></a>?>
 </td>
</tr>
```

What i want to do is that if Green Image is clicked i want **jQuery Dialog** with confirm Button and if user confirm that i want to send ajax request to my Controller Action1 with data `$record['id_to_send'];`.if Red image is clicked after confirmation i want to send ajax request to my Controller Action2 with data `$record['id_to_send'];`

Comment: JQuery UI comes with a nice modal. http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: @Magrangs  how to send ajax request on OK??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send AJAX on OK confirmation:

```js
$( "<div>Confirmation</div>" ).dialog({
   modal:true,
   buttons: {
        "OK": function() {
             sendAjax(); //Your ajax function
             $(this).dialog( "close" );
         },
         "Cancel": function() {
             $(this).dialog( "close" );
         }
   }
});
```

Comment: how to make background disable?? i mean that user is not able to interact with other elements in page when dialog popup

Comment: @Teknords - That's what the `modal: true` does.

Comment: You should set to true the modal option. check the code again.